# BibTeX encoding problem migrating from Windows to OSX

Tags: bibtex, windows, mac, font-encodings

I haven't used JabRef in a long time, basically ever since I moved from Microsoft OS to Mac. Now I am writing my dissertation in LaTeX, and whenever I refer to an entry in my old `.bib` bibliography, the format of German umlauts (ä, ü, ö etc.) is totally messed up. How do I change the encoding in my BibTeX file? I use

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
```

in my preamble, and apart from the bibliography problem, everything works perfectly.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[natbib,style=authoryear-comp, url=false, doi=false,isbn=false,eprint=false]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{[mypath]} %this works 
\begin{document} Here I want to refer to \cite{Lueger1995}. 
\end{document}
```

and here one of those problematic bib-items:

```
@Book{Lueger1995, 
Title = {{Pressesprache}}, 
Author = {Heinz-Helmut Lüger}, 
Publisher = {Max Niemeyer Verlag, Tübingen}, 
Year = {1995}, }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should provide a little example which shows your problem. It has to be compilable and include one of the problematic bib-items.

Comment: Thanks! So here is one of those problematic bib-items:
@Book{Lueger1995,
  Title                    = {{Pressesprache}},
  Author                   = {Heinz-Helmut Lüger},
  Publisher                = {Max Niemeyer Verlag, Tübingen},
  Year                     = {1995},
}
and the way I refer to it would be

\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[natbib,style=authoryear-comp, url=false, doi=false,isbn=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}  
\bibliography{[mypath]} %this works   

\begin{document}
Here I want to refer to \cite{Lueger1995}.
\end{document}

Answer (score 1):

You *shouldn't*   use applemac encoding for .tex files any more! All modern OS understand `UTF8` and, with ascii, it is the only universal format. I have no idea why the default in TeXshop still is applemac, if I'm not mistaken.

You also can use UTF8-encoded .bib files if you make your bibliography with `biblatex/biber`, and JabRef is able to save your .bib files in UTF8 encoding (goto `Preferences -> General` menu).

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I tried that. But when I change applemac encoding to utf8, then it won't even compile anymore, let alone work with references.

Comment: @frauroth: You need to change the encoding of the files themselves. You could also try to you use `bibencoding=ansinew` in the biblatex options (assuming that your bib file is ansinew encoded).

Comment: It's probably because you haven't converted your file to utf8 format. The real encoding must be the same as the declared encoding! Do you not have a security copy of your files? Or you haven't converted correctly. `iconv` does the conversion as a another file and is available for Linux and MacOS X; the problem is that you must be sure of the original encoding.

Comment: @frauroth: Fine. Nevertheless in the long run you should better reencode all your files in utf8. That's easier than a mix of various encodings and will also make it easier to use your files on other OS.